# Handling UIAlertView delegate from C++

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a C++ project on iOS. It mostly uses C++, except for some tasks that require Objective-C. For instance, showing a UIAlert.

So I call the UIAlert from C++. How do I get the result and know what was the button tapped by the user?

This is the implementation of the C++ class calling to Objective-C

```
void iOSBridge::iOSHelper::ShowAlert()
{
    [IsolatedAlert showAlert];
}
```

And here I have the Objective-C implementation:

```
+ (void)show{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" 
                                                    message: @"hello" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

+ (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

}
```

Is there any way to call C++ again from clickedButtonAtIndex delegate?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use self in a class method. And if you can, it'll give you the class meta-object, and that could get messy.

Comment: if the class : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate> works... the problem is how to call the c++ code back :-S

Comment: @JohnCorbett Using `self` in a class method is perfectly valid, and does indeed return the Class object. That said, it's strange to use class methods the way he has done, and as explained by Matt Wilding, among other problems, it will make it hard to do what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing you from calling a C++ class from an Objective C one. You'll need to provide your Objective C class with some sort of a handle to the C++ class, which it will need to store as an instance variable. Then you can do whatever you want with it.

That's going to be awkward to accomplish while you're only using class methods like you are. It'll be better to use instance methods, and then create an instance from the C++ side, provide the instance with a handle, then send messages to the instance instead of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Make the extension of this class as `.mm`

Then have an static var `YourClaas *delegate;` in it

```
+ (void)showAlertWithDelegate:(YourClass*)del{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" 
                                                    message: @"hello" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    delegate = del;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

+ (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   del->buttonClickAtIndex(buttonIndex);
}
```

and define `void buttonClickAtIndex(int index)` method in your `cpp` file

Comment: You can't use instance variables from class methods.

Comment: Making it a global variable will work for a single instance, but if he ever creates more than one at a time, he'll get some really strange results. It's far cleaner and more robust to use a real ivar, in conjunction with instance methods. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @MattWilding my intension here is to show him the way to do it. Yeah you are right but for that he has to consider all the aspect. I'm not going to code for him..